# Using Fresco, will it clear cache automatically? or how to make it to clear cache auto?

Tags: android, image, fresco

I start a new project and plan to use Fresco, but I am afraid my app will be OOM just for the reason that cache is too big, so I wanna know will Fresco clear cache automatically? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Fresco automatically manages the cache and will clear items.
However, if you do not use Fresco correctly (i.e. hold on to the images somewhere), there can be OOMs.

You can read more about Fresco's caches and how to customize them here: http://frescolib.org/docs/caching.html